# Vue-cli webpack-simple, mongodb require problems

Tags: mongodb, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I am trying to create a new project via vue-cli with the webpack-simple template. Everything works until I try to use mongodb.

As soon as I add the line

```
import mongodb from 'mongodb'
```

I get the following error.

```
./node_modules/mongodb/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Development\vue-cli-test\node_modules\mongodb\lib\gridfs'
```

I got rid of this error when I added

```
node: { fs: 'empty' }
```

to my webpack.config.js file.

Now I get the following error

```
./node_modules/require_optional/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module' in 'D:\Development\vue-cli-test\node_modules\require_optional\node_modules\resolve-from'
```

I use node version 8.9.0

Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like webapps are the new smartphones, so I guess we repeat the same answers all over again. Your database connection software does not belong in your web application client. This software is "back end only" so you need to get it out of your build and stop attempting to use it there.

Comment: `fs` package used by `mongodb` is a file system library for Node environment. You can't run it in browser.

Comment: Wow, that's quite embarassing. I don't know how I could confuse this. You guys are absolutely correct. Thanks for waking me up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs/MongoDB cannot be used in front-end code. Send the data to the sever, then have the server save it to the database.